# How can I make SmoothDivScroll start auto-scrolling again after I've manually scrolled using mousewheel and/or hotspots?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I have a SmoothDivScroll plugin on a site I'm working on and it is using the AJAX content feature pulling content from an exteral file. It all works brilliantly but just one thing is bugging me which is that when the page loads the scroller auto-scroll (which is what I want), but when I manually scroll and then stop, it doesn't start auto-scrolling again. Is it possible to do this and can anybody give me some pointers on how to do it?

Best,

Cobain.

Answer (score 2):

instead of changing the original plugin, you may use the autoScrollingStopped callback:

```
    autoScrollingStopped: 
            function() { 
               $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
                       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should find in `jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.3.js` line #430 (as of version 1.3):

```
self.hideHotSpotBackgrounds(250);
```

Then just add after it the following:

```
self.startAutoScrolling();
```

then set using `jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.3.js` instead of minified one - and you're good to go!